# How to clear all keys of all objects and bone?

Tags: animation

Is there any way to clear or delete all the key frames of all object and bones?

I created an animation, but now I only want the model and not the animation. Selecting each bone and deleting every key frame is very tiresome job. I tried selecting all object and pressing *alt* I, but somehow the key frames still come back when I select a single bone.

Answer (score 3):

**Using scripts**

Often for repetitive (& tedious) tasks it is handy to use a small script.

**Remove all actions in file**

Keyframed animation data is stored in an action. To completely remove all keyframed animation data, can remove all actions in the file.

```
import bpy
for a in bpy.data.actions:
    bpy.data.actions.remove(a)
```

**Clear all animation data on scene and scene objects**

To remove animation (actions, NLA, drivers) from scene objects and scene, but keep the actions in file.

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.animation_data_clear()
for o in scene.objects:
    o.animation_data_clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to animations tab, select the object's bone for which you want to delete animation.

2.Enter into *pose mode*,  and Press <kbd>A</kbd> key twice (deselect and selects all bones).

3.Now on the left side, all the animation keys will appear and they turn into orange color indicating that all are selected.

4.Now move your mouse cursor over the curves and hit <kbd>Del</kbd> key then select delete keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have a timeline view open.  (Or a few other choices.)
2. Select all objects.  In object mode.
3. In timeline view, select all.  (Same-ish interface here, just hit 'a' with your mouse cursor over the timeline for me.)
4. Delete keyframes in timeline view.  (x->delete keyframes.)